# all gcloud compute commands fails - Invalid value for project: myproject

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm just starting to play with Google Compute Engine. I can create instances using the web interface, but nothing works from the console:

```
gcloud compute instances create example-instance \
>     --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
>     --image debian-7 \
>     --zone europe-west1-b

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Failed to find image for alias [debian-7] in public image project [debian-cloud].
 - Invalid value for project: myproject
```

It looks like the image is available.

```
$ gcloud compute images list --project debian-cloud --no-standard-images
NAME                                              PROJECT      ALIAS              DEPRECATED STATUS
backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20150929               debian-cloud debian-7-backports            READY
beta-accounts-backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20150930 debian-cloud                               READY
beta-accounts-debian-8-jessie-v20150930           debian-cloud                               READY
debian-7-wheezy-v20150929                         debian-cloud debian-7                      READY
debian-8-jessie-v20150929                         debian-cloud debian-8                      READY
```

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Invalid value for project: myproject

I get an **- Invalid value for project: myproject** message for almost every gcloud command I try.

I can see myproject when I visit https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=1
And from the console:

```
$ gcloud config list project
[core]
project = myproject
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 16):

My mistake.

I mixed project_**name** and project**_id**.

```
 $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID  #(not project name)
```

Comment: this actually helped me out a lot!  I think this is one of those dumb mistakes a lot of people will make.